# select() call with infinit timeout

Tags: sockets, select, cpu

I want to use the select call to send() data from my write socket fd. I am going to ue the non blocking socket implemenation.
Which implementation is better.

```
while(u4BytesSent < u2BufLen)
{

    i4RetVal = send(sockFd, au1Buf + u4BytesSent, (u2BufLen - u4BytesSent));
    if(i4RestVal == -1 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        break;
    }
    i4BytesSent = i4BytesSent + i4RetVal;   
}
```

Will this code hog CPU if send buffer becomes full frequently?

OR

Use Select call with infinite timeout.Will select() have a better performance with CPU hogging and all?

Answer (score 1):

> Will this code hog CPU if send buffer becomes full frequently?

Yes. It will also behave incorrectly (most likely crash), as it will end up adding the error return value of `-1` to `i4BytesSent` repeatedly on error.

Using `select()` with an infinite (or, at least, very long) timeout should work fine. Your process will sleep until data is available on the socket.

Given what you're describing, you would be better off not using non-blocking sockets. There's certainly no point if what you're going to do is just wrap them in `select()` to make write operations blocking anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I cannot change the mode of socket since this is a huge piece of code and can impact other operations. I just want to know that does select() with infinite timeout will consume CPU or thread will go to sleep if socket is not ready for send()

Comment: Well, you could temporarily set the socket as blocking for this function, then set it back as non-blocking afterwards… that being said, yes, `select()` should work fine.